# An alternative to MySQL fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I read that MySQL **fulltext search can cause table locking**. It means people can't insert or update the table when it's being searched on.

I read that there are many **search servers** (Lucence and Sphinx) can do it without table locking and even faster. It **requires many configuration and hard to implement**.

**Is there any other way to use fulltext or some searching like that without using search service?** I don't want to configure one more server other than MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an extra table which will be used only to perform FULLTEXT searches. In your code you have to ensure that all data and actions (create, update, delete) are properly replicated to this table. This solution is also handy if your data tables are running e.g. InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Lucene doesn't need *many configuration* and isn't *hard to implement*. Moreover, it's one of the most popular fulltext search engine, and allows the users to do very precise queries, like "to be or not to be", j?hn d?e, func*, etc.

I already did some database indexing with Lucene, so if you could be a bit more precise about which fields of which tables you wanna index, I can give you pieces of code which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for Sphinxsearch anyway. It has one of APIs close to Mysql, easy to install and configure. Not so universal as Apache Lucene, but jet quick and very helpful in my projects.